# Cannot download and install ffmpeg for python

Tags: python, download, ffmpeg, installation

I'm having a problem with downloading ffmpeg for python. It seems to me that no matter what I do it just doesn't work. 
Btw ,sorry for the images but I still don't know how to post my command prompt on here. So here is the error i'm getting.

[image]

I've already tried "pip install ffmpeg-normalize" and when I do that I get this.

[image]

FYI I already downloaded imageio and that went totally fine. I even have the ffmpeg.py file in imageio. Does anyone know how I can install it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to download ffmpeg

import imageio 
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()

Comment: Hey @BEKK OKK, i tried that and it runs fine but doesn't change anything. I still have the same error.